# Ito Isometry and quadratic variation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Here is a confusion regarding stochastic integrals. Let
$Y_t=\int_0^tW_sds$ where $W_t$ is a Brownian Motion. Now $dY_t=W_tdt$. So from this expression one can conclude that $dY_t \cdot dY_t=d[Y_t,Y_t]$ where $[\ ]$ is the quadratic variation process and it must be zero as $dt \cdot dt =0$. But people apply Fubini-stochastic integral exchange trick and see $Y_t=\int_0^t(t-u)dW_u$. So by applying Ito isometry one can see that $E(Y_t^2)=\int_0^t(t-u)^2du \neq 0$. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Why this discrepancy?

Comment: $\mathsf E(Y^2_t)$ is not its quadratic variation. Also, I am not sure that you did an integration by parts in a correct way. There shall be a term $tW_t$

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 5):

Every step is correct, including the identities $Y_t=\displaystyle\int_0^tW_s\mathrm ds=\int_0^t(t-s)\mathrm dW_s$ and $[Y]_t=0$, except the underlying assertion that the process $Y^2-[Y]$ should be a martingale and consequently that $\mathbb E(Y_t^2)$ and $\mathbb E([Y]_t)$ should coincide for every $t$.

Recall that the quadratic variation process $[Y]$ is defined as
$[Y]_t=Y_t^2-2\displaystyle\int_0^tY_s\mathrm dY_s$. In particular, $Y^2-[Y]=2\displaystyle\int_0^\cdot Y\mathrm dY$ is a martingale when $Y$ is, but not otherwise.

Here, $Y$ is not a martingale since, for every $s\lt t$, $\mathbb E(Y_t\mid\mathcal F_s)=Y_s+(t-s)W_s\ne Y_s$.

**Edit:** A general method (which is not *a trick*) to compute $\mathbb E(Y_t^2)$ is indeed to use Itô's formula for $Y^2$. One gets
$$
\mathrm d(Y_t^2)=2Y_t\mathrm dY_t+\mathrm d[Y]_t=2Y_tW_t\mathrm dt.
$$
Fubini on $\Omega\times[0,t]$ with the measure $\mathbb P\otimes\mathrm{Leb}$ yields
$$
\mathbb E(Y_t^2)=\mathbb E\left(\int_0^t2Y_sW_s\mathrm ds\right)=\int_0^t2\mathbb E(Y_sW_s)\mathrm ds.
$$
Fubini again yields
$$
2\mathbb E(Y_sW_s)=2\int_0^s\mathbb E(W_uW_s)\mathrm du=\int_0^s2u\mathrm du=s^2,
$$
hence
$$
\mathbb E(Y_t^2)=\int_0^ts^2\mathrm ds=\frac{t^3}3.
$$

Comment: Then how can one use Ito formula to compute $E(Y_t^2)$ though another method could be given by approximating $W_t$ by some representations in dyadic intervals and then computing the lebesgue integral $\int_0^tW_sds$ and finally taking its square and limit.But I do not want to use this method and instead want to use some trick.Is there any..??

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: Thank you very much Did...But my last doubt is what about applying Ito isometry if the integrand involves "t".For example the same $t^3/3$ result can be got if i apply ito isometry to $\int_0^t(t-s)dW_s$.please clarify ...!!

Comment: Then what about it? I do not feel responsible for unsubstantiated assertions in other answers. Of course the same result is obtained by Ito isometry even if the integrand involves $t$!

Comment: Thanks Did ...but I guess you can not apply ito isometry as $t-s$ will not be adapted to $F_s$.Can you clarify this point lastly?Thank you very very much.

Comment: Sorry? $t-s$ is deterministic hence adapted to **every** sigma-algebra.

Comment: Why can we apply Ito's formula to $Y^2_t$? Is $Y^2_t$ a semimartingale?

Comment: @Monolite Because $Y$ is, and because $y\mapsto y^2$ is regular ($C^2$).

Answer (score -1):

Your second representation is correct, but you cannot treat it as a stochastic integral (so will not be a martingale) as the integrand depends on the end point of the integral, $t$. Even if it were a martingale, you cannot apply the Itou isometry to it for the same reason. Basically, the problem is that $Y_t$ are integrands against completely different processes in the second representation.

Comment: The result of your partial copying of my answer is an odd mixture of true (but irrelevant) assertions and of false results. For example, one can very well *treat it as a stochastic integral* even if *the integrand depends on the end point of the integral*, one can very well *apply the Itou* (sic) *isometry* and both *representations* yield exactly identical processes.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean to copy your answer (I posted without refreshing for a while then noticed you posted and admittedly edited it to note it won't be a martingale). Yes, sorry. I should have just said "we cannot treat it as a stochastic integral _process_ (only a stochastic integral up to a single fixed time), so it will not be a martingale". 

I generally use Itou because it conforms with the most logical and easy to type transliteration system for Japanese. Wikipedia uses Itō, and a variety of others have been used, so I don't think Ito is the "correct" one.